# How to display an image as a property in JavaScript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
  //construtor created
   function Blog(text, date, image) {
        this.show_image = function(src, width, height, alt){
                        var img = document.createElement("img");
                            img.src = src;
                            img.width = width;
                            img.height = height;
                            img.alt = alt;
                            document.body.appendChild(img);
                    }

    }
 //instance

    var blog = [new Blog("hello!,Welcome to my blog1.", new Date("10/21/2012"),'show_image("images/overlay.png", 20,30, "Google Logo")'),
```

Hey m calling an image in above instance for that i've written a function show_image performs that part  but the image is not getting displayed...please tell me what is wrong here ...please modify it...I'm new in javascript programming..
        I

Comment: Do you call `show_image()` somewhere?

Comment: When calling the function show_images, you have wrapped it within single quotes. Remove it so that the function gets executed.

Comment: hey its inside the instance you can see the third  property in it where m calling an overlay.png images

Comment: You're not calling anything, it's a string!

Comment: hey hop tell from where i should learn javascript programming

Answer (score 0):

i have no idea why are you creating constructor and all..this can be done, with creating a simple function

try this

```
function show_image(src, width, height, alt){
                    var img = document.createElement("img");
                        img.src = src;
                        img.width = width;
                        img.height = height;
                        img.alt = alt;
                        document.body.appendChild(img);
  }



$(document).ready(function(){  //if using jquery
   show_image("images/overlay.png", 20,30, "Google Logo");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not calling the show_images function. You are just passing a string and that is not going to help.

Remember before finding out why the particular block of code is not working, you need to find out if that block is executed at all.

This is one more way you make it work.

```
function Blog(text, date) {

    this.show_image = function (src, width, height, alt) {

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = src;
        img.width = width;
        img.height = height;
        img.alt = alt;
        document.body.appendChild(img);
    }

}
//instance

var blog = new Blog("hello!,Welcome to my blog1.", new Date("10/21/2012"));
blog.show_image("images/overlay.png", 20,30, "Google Logo");
```

Comment: Anywhere except w3schools. Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide